# use iris efficiently to combine iris.analysis&aggregated while outputing time of occurence

Tags: performance, time-series, python-iris

I am using python/iris to get annual extreme values from daily data. I use `aggregated_by('season_year', iris.analysis.MIN)` to get the extreme values, but I need to also know when in each year they occur. I have written the code below, but this is really slow, so I am wondering whether anyone knows maybe an `iris` build-in way to do it, or can otherwise think of another way that is more efficient?

Thank you!

```py
#--- get daily data
cma = iris.load_cube('daily_data.nc')

#--- get annual extremes
c_metric = cma.aggregated_by('season_year', iris.analysis.MIN)

#--- add date of when the extremes are occurring
extrdateli=[]

#loop over all years
for mij in range(c_metric.data.shape[0]):
#
    # get extreme value
    m = c_metric.data[mij]
    #
    #get values for this year
    cma_thisseasyr = cma.extract(iris.Constraint(season_year=lambda season_year:season_year==c_metric.coord('season_year').points[mij]))
    #
    #get date in data cube for when this extreme occurs and print add as string to a list
    extradateli += [ str(c_metric.coord('season_year').points[mij])+':'+','.join([''.join(_) for _ in zip([str(_) for _ in cma_thisseasyr.coord('day').points[np.where(cma_thisseasyr.data==m)]], [str(_) for _ in cma_thisseasyr.coord('month').points[np.where(cma_thisseasyr.data==m)]], [str(_) for _ in cma_thisseasyr.coord('year').points[np.where(cma_thisseasyr.data==m)]])])]

#add this list to the metric cube as attribute
c_metric.attributes['date_of_extreme_value'] = ' '.join(extrdateli)

#--- save to file
iris.save('annual_min.nc')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the slow part is where you extract the values for each season year.  You can speed this up a bit by dispensing with the `lambda`, i.e:

```
iris.Constraint(season_year=c_metric.coord('season_year').points[mij])
```

If this is still too slow, you could work directly on the `numpy` arrays in your cube.  Slicing numpy arrays is much faster than extracting from cubes.  For simplicity, the example below assumes you have a time coordinate.

```
import iris
import numpy as np
import iris.coord_categorisation as cat

#--- create a dummy data cube
ndays = 12 * 365 + 3  # 12 years of data
tcoord = iris.coords.DimCoord(range(ndays), units='days since 2001-02-01',
                              standard_name='time')

cma = iris.cube.Cube(np.random.normal(0, 1, ndays), long_name='blah')
cma.add_dim_coord(tcoord, 0)
cat.add_season_year(cma, 'time')

#--- get annual extremes
c_metric = cma.aggregated_by('season_year', iris.analysis.MIN)

#--- add date of when the extremes are occurring
extrdateli=[]

#loop over all years
for mij in range(c_metric.data.shape[0]):
    #
    #get extreme value
    m = c_metric.data[mij]
    #
    #get values for this year
    year_index = cma.coord('season_year').points == c_metric.coord('season_year').points[mij]
    temperatures_this_syear = cma.data[year_index]
    dates_this_syear = tcoord.units.num2date(tcoord.points[year_index])
    #
    #get date in data cube for when this extreme occurs and print add as string to a list
    extreme_dates = dates_this_syear[temperatures_this_syear==m]
    extrdateli += [ str(c_metric.coord('season_year').points[mij])+':'+','.join(str(date) for date in extreme_dates)]


#add this list to the metric cube as attribute
c_metric.attributes['date_of_extreme_value'] = ' '.join(extrdateli)
```